# Unembed NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

When you drag an NSTableView to a xib in Xcode 5, it puts it inside a scroll view and clip view. I don't want the table view inside those containers, but the Editor -> Unembed command is grayed out. I've tried selecting every element in the hierarchy but it doesn't enable for any of them. How can I get my table view out of the container?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you can; at best you could select the Bordered Scroll View that it's embedded in and turn off its "Show Horizontal Scroller", "Show Vertical Scroller" & "Automatically Hide Scroller" behaviors.